# Objective-c IOS repeating UILocalNotification set to date in past

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdate, uilocalnotification

What if i'll set the UILocalNotification fire date (alarm time) to some time in past and make this notification repeating. Will it notify me after the next time the interval will pass?

example:
I set the notification to yesterday 10:00 AM and make it to repeat every day. Will it fire today at 10:00 AM, or it won't because the first notification was set to time in past?

Comment: did you try it? if it will not works, then you can try make notification from today.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

Same thing on iOS 7.

I tested this in the simulator by setting a repeating reminder in the past and then moving the clock forward to just before it would fire in a weeks time. It didn't fire.

iOS 6